# How to use multiple helpers in handlebars

Tags: nested, handlebars.js, helper

I have written two helpers namely `i18n` and `toLowerCase` as following:

```
/*
* Returns lowercase of a string
*/
Handlebars.registerHelper('toLowerCase', function(value) {
  if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
    return value.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    return '';
  }
});
```

I have a string which should be converted to lowercase first and then should be localized using i18n helper. Both these helpers work/run fine.

These lines are working fine. (Tested)

```
{{toLowerCase status }}
{{i18n status}}
```

But I want something like this.I have tried this:

```
{{i18n {{toLowerCase status }} }}
```

But this throws syntax error as 
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 88:

```
..div>      {{ i18n  {{toLowerCase stat
----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'OPEN'
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781916/is-it-possible-with-handlebars-to-nested-helpers-inside-the-options-hash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handlesbars supports *[Subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions)* now, so you could just do:

```
{{i18n (toLowerCase status) }}
```

(notice, those are *parens* `()`, not curly braces `{}`, for the inside helper)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using https://github.com/mateusmaso/handlebars.nested (be aware that it allows only one level of nesting, though). As far as I know, there's no built-in support on Handlebars for this, though you can use some of the workarounds in the question I linked in comments.