# "if" handlebar inside a component handlebar in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember, I know that I can include classes with if statements using the {{if}} handlebar. However, how can I do this inside a component handlebar?

For example, how can I do something like this:

`{{myComponent class="my-class {{if isThisTrue 'true-class' 'false-class'}}" }}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to nest helpers inside the options hash with handlebars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781916/is-it-possible-to-nest-helpers-inside-the-options-hash-with-handlebars)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the curly braces can't be nested there is a syntax called nested helper to do so, and it works for most of the helpers like `if`, `unless`, `concat`, and family:

```
{{myComponent class=(concat "my-class " (if isThisTrue 'true-class' 'false-class'))}}
```

You have to use `concat` here since you're putting together a static and a dynamic portion of the string together.

Answer (score -2):

You can use,

```
{{my-component class="my-class" classNameBindings="isThisTrue:true-class:false-class"}}
```